Player Movement Problem (Java Graphics 2D)
I can't make the character do what he was doing before jumping, after jumping.
There is a keyReleased method to receive the last released key that was pressed, and this method means that, for example, I am pressing D and SPACE to jump to the right, then I release SPACE and D is forgotten by the program. So, I can't know what the character was doing before releasing the key to resume that action.
Im brazillian so some variables will be in portuguese
pula: jump
pulou: jumped
imagem: image
botaoPressionado: keyPressed
moveParaADireita: moveToTheRight
moveParaAEsquerda: moveToTheLeft
agacha: crouch
comeceEsseMovimento: initThisMove
Here is the code:
    private boolean blocked = false;

    private Player player;
    private int x, y, dx, dy;
    Image imagem;
    private int altura, largura;
    private boolean direita = false;
    private boolean esquerda = false;
    private final int GRAVITY = 1;
    private final int JUMP_FORCE = -20;
    private final int GROUND_Y = 750;
    private int yVel;

    boolean moving = false;

    public Player2() {
        x = 100;
        y = GROUND_Y;
        yVel = 0;

    }

    public void update() {
        x += dx;
        yVel += GRAVITY;
        y += yVel;

        if (y >= GROUND_Y) {
            y = GROUND_Y;
            yVel = 0;
        }
    }

    public void jump() {
        if (y == GROUND_Y) {
            yVel = JUMP_FORCE;
        }
    }

    public String listaDeMoves = null;
    private boolean movendo;
    private boolean block;
    private ArrayList<Movimento> listMoves = new ArrayList<>();


    void keyPressed(KeyEvent botaoPressionado) {

        switch (botaoPressionado.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                moveParaADireita();
                listMoves.add(new Movimento("andouParaADireita"));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                moveParaAEsquerda();
                listMoves.add(new Movimento("andouParaAEsquerda"));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                listMoves.add(new Movimento("agachou"));
                agacha();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                nadaAinda();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                listMoves.add(new Movimento("pulou"));
                pula();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                Menu menu = new Menu();
                menu.setVisible(true);
                break;
        }

    }

    private void menu() {
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        menu.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void pula() {
        jump();
        moving = true;
        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__Jump.gif");
        imagem = referencia.getImage();
    }

    private void agacha() {
        if (!moving) {
            ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__Crouch.gif");
            imagem = referencia.getImage();
            blocked = true;
        }
    }

    private void moveParaAEsquerda() {
        dx = -5;
        moving = true;
        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__RunBehind.gif");
        imagem = referencia.getImage();
        direita = false;
        esquerda = true;
    }

    private void moveParaADireita() {
        dx = 5;
        moving = true;
        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__RunNormal.gif");
        imagem = referencia.getImage();
        direita = true;
        esquerda = false;
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent botaoSoltado) {
        int tecla = botaoSoltado.getKeyCode();
//        ImageIcon referencia = new //ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__Idle.gif");
//        imagem = referencia.getImage();
        blocked = false;
        moving = false;
        if(tecla == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

        }else{
            dx = 0;
        }
    }

    private void comeceEsseMovimento(String movimentoAtual) {
        switch (movimentoAtual){
            case "andouParaADireita":
                moveParaADireita();
                break;
            case "andouParaAEsquerda":
                moveParaAEsquerda();
                break;
            case "pulou":
                pula();
                break;
            case "agachou":
                agacha();
                break;
        }
    }


    void load() {
        ImageIcon referencia = new ImageIcon("res\\Colour2//player//120x80_gifs//__Idle.gif");
        imagem = referencia.getImage();
        altura = imagem.getHeight(null);
        largura = imagem.getWidth(null);
    }

I tried several validations but none worked. I tried to create an arrayList that receives all the movements made and when the KeyReleased method runs, it sees what the last movement was other than the jump and runs that movement, but it didn't work because it ran this every time the method ran and it wasn't well validated, so any previous movement was repeated when releasing any key. Example: I'm jumping so I stop jumping and start walking. So when I release the walk button, the character jumps because that's what he was doing before he walked.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I like your idea of having a list of actions, but we need to be smart in how we maintain it.
I'd recommend this approach:
    Stack<KeyEvent> pressedKeyEvents = new Stack<>();

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        pressedKeyEvents.add(keyEvent);

        // this is your preexisting logic. For this approach
        // to work it needs to be in a separate method:
        doKeyPressed(keyPressed);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        pressedKeyEvents.removeIf(existingKeyEvent -> keyEvent.getKeyChar() == existingKeyEvent.getKeyChar());
        
        // insert your preexisting keyReleased logic here, it doesn't
        // matter if it's in a separate method or not
        
        if (!pressedKeyEvents.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = pressedKeyEvents.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                KeyEvent activeEvent = pressedKeyEvents.get(i);
                if (activeEvent.getKeyChar() == ' ') {
                    // you probably don't want to reissue a jump event even
                    // if the user is still holding down the SPACE key?
                    continue;
                } else {
                    doKeyPressed(activeEvent);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

As you release each key: we remove it from the stack.
But when you release a key: we'll replay the other most recently pressed key (if one exists). We may need to ignore certain keystrokes that shouldn't repeat (like jumping); you can customize that as needed.
You enumerated two scenarios to focus on. You could write these up as separate unit tests. (Scenario A: press D, press SPACE, release SPACE, does the character keep moving to the right? Scenario B: press SPACE, release SPACE, press D, release D, does the character stop moving?)
You could also test this Scenario C:

Press D (character moves to the right)
Press A (character moves to the left)
Release A (character moves to the right)
Release D (character stops)

(That expected behavior is subjective; you could also argue that pressing D and A at the same time should cancel each other out. Whatever behavior you expect: you can express it as a unit test so your app stays consistent.)
